# How does a text file distinguish a letter and number in binary

Tags: binary

In a text file you can write both the letter 'A' and number '65'. But obviously one of these data will be saved with different bits while the ASCII standard gives the letter 'A' the binary code for 65. Does a .txt file use some sort of container for different interpretations of binary? How does this work?

Comment: about your particular confusion between 'A' and '65', the answer is that 'A' has a value encoding of 65, but '65' (note the quotation mark! it means this is a string, and not a number!) are two letters, '6' and '5', where the letter '6' encodes into the *value* 54, and '5' encodes into 53. So the representation of the string 'A65' would be the three bytes [65][54][53]

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean by container. But any file, may it be a text file, image, videos, executables, etc. are stored in binary. Now the interpretation of a file is dependent on the particular program that will read it. As for text editors, it will interpret the content based on a selected [character enconding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Most text editor will try to [auto detect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187174) the encoding for a given file and some might have a default expected enconding.